# sc2reader could not load my replay file

Tags: python, file, load

I'm new in sc2reader. I tried to load a replay, but I received the following error. Also, I tried different replay files that SC2 could play them. My code is as follow:

```
from sc2reader.factories import SC2Factory

path = 'D:/Code/Test/replays/LerilakCrest.SC2Replay'
sc2 = SC2Factory()
replay = sc2.load_replay(path)

print('done')
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "D:/Code/Test/read.py", line 9, in <module>
replay = sc2.load_replay(path)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\factories\sc2factory.py", line 85, in load_replay
return self.load(Replay, source, options, **new_options)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\factories\sc2factory.py", line 137, in load
return self._load(cls, resource, filename=filename, options=options)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\factories\sc2factory.py", line 146, in _load
obj = cls(resource, filename=filename, factory=self, **options)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\resources.py", line 262, in __init__
self._read_data(data_file, self._get_reader(data_file))
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\resources.py", line 592, in _read_data
self.raw_data[data_file] = reader(data, self)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\readers.py", line 33, in __call__
) for i in range(data.read_bits(5))],
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\decoders.py", line 252, in read_aligned_string
return self._buffer.read_string(count, encoding)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\decoders.py", line 108, in read_string
return self.read_bytes(count).decode(encoding)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 2):

Joy, an other user of sc2reader!

I know that problem, it's due to the fact than your version of sc2reader is older than your replay.
Personnaly, I've resolved my problem by doing :

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/StoicLoofah/sc2reader@lotv#egg=sc2reader --upgrade
```

That's the most recent version of sc2reader actually and it supports LotV.

Comment: Cool. I use sc2reader 0.6.5 on windows. I tried eaither new replays (my own replays) and old replays from [Synnaeve dataset](http://emotion.inrialpes.fr/people/synnaeve/TLGGICCUP_gosu_data.7z) too.

Comment: My sc2 reader version is 0.7.0rc0.  
Try to update with the command I've posted (minus the sudo if you're on windows), I'm pretty sure than it's where your problem come from.

Comment: I guess the problem is related to the [replays dataset](http://emotion.inrialpes.fr/people/synnaeve/TLGGICCUP_gosu_reps.7z). After upgrading, I could read my own replays, but I couldn't read mentioned replays, and the error is as follow:     `

`File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\site-packages\sc2reader\resources.py", line 255, in __init__
    raise exceptions.MPQError("Unable to construct the MPQArchive", e)
sc2reader.exceptions.MPQError: (u'Unable to construct the MPQArchive', ValueError('Invalid file header.',))`

Comment: Just now, I realized that my dataset includes replays from SC I. Is it the case? So how can I load replays from SC I?